# Android pass variable from Java activity to Kotlin adapter

Tags: android, kotlin

I don't know why I'm blanking on this... but I've got a java activity which displays comments... and I need to pass the id of the photo that's being commented onto the adapter that gets all of the comments. The adapter is called CommentGrabber:

```
commentGrabber = new CommentGrabber(this);
```

...and it's executed like this:

```
private void requestComment() {
    commentGrabber.getComment();
}
```

The "id" variable of the current photo can be had at any time by getting its intent but I've saved it to a string called "photo_id."

```
final String photo_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
```

This is what the adapter side looks like:

```
fun getComment(String photo_id) {
//this is where the function is handled
}
```

So I just need to figure out how to get the "photo_id" from my comment activity to "getComment" in the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have the adapter method expect an argument like below:

```
fun getComment(photo_id : String) {
    // from there then pass the photo_id to the service call
}
```

You would then call it like so:

```
adapter.getComment(photo_id);
```

Whenever you want to fetch comments by id.

I hope this makes sense. If you need further clarification, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Sorry... I pasted the wrong code (updated now). What you've got above is java and THAT's the part that should be in Kotlin that I'm confused about. The actual function looks like this: fun getComment() { //stuff }

Comment: Figured it out. If you just change the "public void" java stuff to "fun getComment..." Kotlin... I'll accept your answer. That's really all the problem was. It's just a bit different in Kotlin.

Comment: Oh okay, that is good. I am glad you are fine now. In case of any further questions, I am always here to help.